# Is there a more current version of WMD Markdown other than derobins?

Tags: markdown, wmd

I've started using [derobins wmd markdown](https://github.com/derobins/wmd), and I really like the way it performs and integrates with my system.  I do however have one MAJOR issue whereby the `<ol>` the `<ul>` and the `<blockqote>` doesn't work in Google Chrome or RockMelt.

I see that it's working here on StackOverflow, but I know they're making a lot of modifications.

Can anyone suggest a better version of WMD Markdown?

Here's a screenshot of what my editor looks like when I click "blockquote" in Chrome
[image: Google Chrome screws up wmd markdown]

Comment: Apparently this problem is due to a bug in the JS engine Chrome uses. I believe the fix is a bit of a hack. I too would like to find the version SO actually uses though. Hoping someone puts it out there (github?) for us. I've not found it yet :(

Comment: This is the same info I've come up with.  I took a look at the SO source, but being obfuscated, it's not easy to decipher.  I tried [MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) too, but didn't really like how complicated it is. I'm looking for quick and painless.

Comment: Me too. Apparently there was supposed to be a version 3 of the WMD editor (I guess the current one is 2.x). However, I believe derobins  was busy [doing a PHd](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49511/did-wmd-3-ever-come-out) and therefore hadn't time to dedicate to it. Still hoping it materialises at some point, but for now the current SO version would be ideal.

Comment: what do you mean by the current SO version? I tried to take a look at the SO source, but being minified and obfuscated makes it really hard to deal with. Do you know of somewhere where Jeff or someone has posted it?

Comment: No, that's what I mean. Until version 3 arrives, an ideal solution (for me) would be to have the current SO version (sans obfuscation). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be available.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: Stack Overflow have released [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) which fixes all the above bugs. Use that one instead. Original answer below...

---

Technically, the [WMD version from Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/) is the official one maintained by some of the SO staff (browse the source to get your hands on the actual code). However, it still suffers from the bug you describe above. In fact it doesn't match up to SO's current version in many regards.

Yang's answer does work, but I took a look at what Stack Overflow actually does by de-minifying their addBlankLines function. They add the following code to said function between lines 1498 and 1500:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome/)) {
    "X".match(/()./);
}
```

I can't fathom what on earth this code does, but it works! And it's what Stack Overflow is using right now so it can't be too bad :)

Comment: Cool, when I get back to my project I'll give it a try. For now, I'll pass along a big ol' +1

Comment: @dino, by the way there are several other bugs in the code that don't appear on Stack Overflow, which you can see at http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/issues/list

Comment: @Dis..: thanks for inform :) By the way, do you know any more current version of WMD to download? Still that Google Code page hasn't download link...

Comment: @dino, no sorry, there is no "single download" package that I know of. But if you [browse the source](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/source/browse/) of the Google Code project you can get all the files individually. Or use SVN to checkout a copy.

Comment: @yehuda if you are looking for a markdown editor, use PageDown instead (link in updated answer).

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat  is it worth changing all my code now, i have finally got it all working? Also, is it just as easy?

Answer (score 2):

open **wmd.js**, comment or delete line 2081 and line 2264, which is:

```
chunk.addBlankLines(); //-----line 2081
```

and:

```
chunk.addBlankLines(nLinesBefore, nLinesAfter, true); //------line 2264
```

**I don't know why**, but I got it from debug and debug for a full day. I hope it is usefull.

Comment: amazing.. it solves link problem in Chrome. But lines a little bit different. I put it as a patch here: [WMD Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/issues/detail?id=13)